# Youtube api iframe with ipad ios7

Tags: ios, ipad, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

With the latest versions of `iOS`, iPad and iPhone, the Youtube player (iframe js version) doesn't work anymore. I know the new restrictions of Apple regarding autoplay embed video... The problem is that also if I tap over the Youtube video player on the iPad device, the stream does not start, but it just remains buffering.

Do you know hot to fix it?

Comment: Please give some more detail, friend.

Comment: I also encountered this problem for 3 days without updated IOS (I updated after). But this changement exist, and events and playVideo() method doesn't not works at all.  I'm looking for a solution too.

Answer (score 2):

for iOS devices, you should use the HTML5 not js API.

just use the code below to add the video to your app:

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID";
NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                      <html><head>\
                      <style type=\"text/css\">\
                      iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
                      body {\
                      background-color: transparent;\
                      color: white;\
                      }\
                      </style>\
                      </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                      <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                      </body></html>",videoURL];

self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
```

**EDIT:**

As per the comments, you are using HTML5 instead of Objective-C, just replace all the code in your Demo.html with the code below:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qbexOeoH5hg" allowfullscreen frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

This should work on iOS :)

**NOTE:**

Protected videos can't be embedded as per YouTube's policy, so when trying to play the video mentioned in the example, you will get an error saying `"This video contains content from "Copyright owner"(VEVO in our example) it is restricted from playback on certain sites, watch it on YouTube"`, other unprotected videos works on all devices.

Comment: well, this isn't server side code, it is ObjectiveC, but since you are  using HTML5, can you post how you add the iframe to your HTML5 code ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5ldj1z9c5uij7vd/yEsIh1O_9j

Comment: above the link to take a look on my code! thank you so much!

Comment: sorry for the delay, I was in a meeting :), I will take a look & feedback...

Comment: Thank you so much i'll try this evening! :) but if i want to load the src dinamically? In this way i can't..

Comment: i have a json file with a lot of video id's to load on relative click

Comment: use javascript to change the src of the iframe :)

Comment: thank you! i've tried and now with ipad the video starts, but then shows the text "video is not available." The same video on android mobile device works.. why?? Thank you